# Logging the current filename

Tags: cakephp

Is there a way to log the filename/class name/function and/or line number, where the `$this->log` was called?

I could not find this in the documentation for `$this->log` or `CakeLog::write ()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the default PHP constants for this. For example:

```
CakeLog::write('debug', 'Oops, something went wrong in ' .
    __FILE__ . ' on line' . __LINE__ . ' within the class ' . get_class()
);
```

That should give you all the info you need.

Comment: Thanks.  Borrowed the above syntax into $this->log format. $this->log('Oops, something went wrong in ' .__FILE__ . ' on line' . __LINE__ . ' within the class ' . get_class(), 'debug');

Comment: @Joe Smith You could also write a new function for this and use [`debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). This might be useful when you have a lot of `__FILE__`/`__LINE__` messages to log.

Answer (score 0):

Or more handy, just log the trace:

```
$e = new Exception; $this->log($e->getTraceAsString());
```

will log you calls with files & line numbers that lead to that particular log() statement.